# Ajax & JQUERY formData not appending to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need some assistance as im not sure what's going on, i have tried this same code on other opportunities and it worked, but for some reason now it is not, i need to upload a file via JQuery and Ajax, here is the html form:

```
<form  enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formulario">
                                <input  type="text" id="atributo1" placeholder="Ingrese atributo 1...">
                                <input  type="text" id="atributo2" placeholder="Ingrese atributo 2..."><br>
                                SELECT:
                                <select id="atributo3">
                                    <option value="opcion1" selected>Opcion 1</option>
                                    <option value="opcion2">Opcion 2</option>
                                    <option value="opcion3">Opcion 3</option>
                                </select><br><br>
                                <input  type="file" id="atributon">
                                <button type="button" onclick="Alta()">Crear</button>
                                <button type="button" onclick="Listar()">Volver</button>
                            </form>
```

Below it's the receiving end from the js:

```
function Alta(){

    var form = new FormData($("#formulario")[0]);

    form.append("queHacer","Alta");

    console.log(form);

    $.ajax({url: "nexo.php", type: "POST", data: form, contentType: false, processData: false})
    .then(function(exito){

                 $("#contenidoinner").html(exito);

                },function(error){

                 $("#contenidoinner").html(error);

               });
}
```

The PHP code its a simple var_dump to verify:

```
switch($_POST['queHacer']){

            case "Alta": 


                echo var_dump($_FILES).var_dump($_POST);            
            break;
}
```

But when i do both VAR_DUMPS the $_FILES is empty:

"array(0) { } array(1) { ["queHacer"]=> string(4) "Alta" }"

Not sure what i'm doing wrong as i have another program with this same code and it's working.

Comment: You need to use the "onSubmit" clause in the props of a trigger embedded (e.g. a button) in the form to submit your data.

Comment: I've done it w/o submit in the past and worked, anyhow i tried the onsubmit just in case but it's still passing the $_Files as array(0) {
}

Comment: you did not put a name in your input(s)

Comment: That did it! How do i validate your answer to close the question? Thanks!